# How to change button color in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parsing, button, colors

I am trying to change the colors of the buttons when a statement is true.

```
 void Start()
     {
         if ((int.Parse(gameObject.name)) >= GameController.Instance.CurrentLevel + 1)
         {
             gameObject.GetComponent<Image>().color = new Color(96, 96, 96, 255);
         }
     }
```

I thought it was like this but the colors won't change when loaded. Does anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity's Color class/constructor accepts floats ranging from 0 to 1 instead of 0-255. Change them accordingly and you should see the desired result.

Comment: so you mean i need to do Color(0.96, 0.96, 0.96, 0.255) ?

Comment: 96 out of 255 is 0.37~ What in means is you can do `96f / 255` to have the exact value. What is 255 / 255 ? 1, so you can have `(96f / 255, 96f / 255, 96f / 255, 1)`. Don't forget to have a float value, `96f` <- See the f.

Comment: Thank! that helpt a lot.